# Fatal error: Class CI_Session_files_driver contains 1 abstract method

Tags: php, codeigniter

> Fatal error: Class CI_Session_files_driver contains 1 abstract method
>   and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining
>   methods (SessionHandlerInterface::open) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\cmms2\system\libraries\Session\drivers\Session_files_driver.php
>   on line 49

this error keeps on showing up while i'm working on my localhost xampp web app projec. I'm using codeigniter by the way. What do you think is the reason this shows up?
These are the only codes that I've done with session.

```
  $this->session->set_userdata($data);
    $autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session');
    $config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
    $config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
    $config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
    $config['sess_save_path'] = sys_get_temp_dir();
    $config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
    $config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
    $config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: show which class are u using for extend?

Comment: CI_Session_driver is an abstract class. you need to extend with CI_Session class.

Comment: @devpro posted the codes that i dealt with session

Comment: check which class r u using for extend??? if you are extending with CI_Session_driver just change with CI_Session

Comment: @treblaluch i need your code as well

Comment: @Abdulla what code are u talking about? those are the only ones i've dealt with code igniter

Comment: @devpro you mean in the session_files_driver.php? its extending CI_Session_driver

Comment: yes, You need to extend CI_Session, not CI_Session_files_driver.

Comment: @devpro class CI_Session_files_driver extends CI_Session_driver implements SessionHandlerInterface  this is what it looks like. I changed but there is an error.

Comment: You shouldn't change System files.

Comment: @Tpojka i didn't change anything. just those session files. but why des this error occurs. since i upgraded to the new xampp with php 7.

Comment: How do you mean "just those session files"? - everything should work without any changes. For php version related question, I'm suggesting you to ask on [their forum](http://forum.codeigniter.com).

Comment: @Tpojka i mean those codes are the only ones i have touched. Are you good in codeigniter?

Comment: Nothing shouldn't be changed in `system` directory. Is code you posted here in one or multiple files? Autoload should be in `$config` array of `APPPATH . 'config/autoload.php'` file, `$config['sess_save_path']` should be string of absolute path, NOT temporary directory. Lot of code here doesn't fit CodeIgniter [docs](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/).

Comment: @Tpojka any suggestions on sess_save_path? autload is in autoload.php  i posted it their because i configured it and its related to session.

Comment: You can check suggestion and recomendation in comments for any line in file. Just above the the config line, there is comment that explains what should you set and how. [Config file](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/config/config.php).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intermittent PHP Abstract Class Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42503240/intermittent-php-abstract-class-error)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please restart apache server if not working then download CodeIgniter again and replace your system/ directory with a fresh one.

Comment: It work for me. I have just restart my apache server. Thanks for it

Comment: Right, it's just a problem of apache server some time we use our system on sleep mode for a while and then it's happen. At first it's spoil the mind because in error we didn't get any thing which relate with the apache server.

Comment: yep! happened all of a sudden to my perfectly working CI app after my machine remained for couple of hours on standby, Apache restart fixed it right away!

Comment: It works. +1 for this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This is a [PHP bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42503240/intermittent-php-abstract-class-error) that in my observation triggers on Windows, Apache+mod_php.

*(old answer below)*

---

`SessionHandlerInterface::open()` *is* implemented by [system/libraries/Session/drivers/Session_files_driver.php](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/3.0.4/system/libraries/Session/drivers/Session_files_driver.php#L113) in CodeIgniter.

The only way to trigger the error you've shown is by modifying that file, which you're not supposed to do.

Comment: It's not that simple, I've encountered this error at random time, many time, even tough I'm absolutely never modify that file and I always use new copy of CodeIgniter when start creating a project. I'd guess that this is a "rare bug" of CI which could happen on PHP7 in certain environment/machine ... IDK

Comment: You're right, it's not that simple. It's funny that right after that you assume it is a CI issue though.

Comment: Is this issue happen on other framework as well? (because I only use CI)

Comment: `CI_Session_files_driver` is belong to CI, isn't it? That's why I thought it be.

Comment: Yes it does happen in other frameworks (and I had already updated the answer to reflect this), but that's besides the point. If you actually look at the code, you'll know there's no way this is the framework's fault.

Answer (score 0):

Go in System folder
/system/libraries/Session

Then comment the code in SessionHandlerInterface.php

```
interface SessionHandlerInterface {

// public function open($save_path, $name);
// public function close();
// public function read($session_id);
// public function write($session_id, $session_data);
// public function destroy($session_id);
// public function gc($maxlifetime);
}
```

Let's try your code is working or not