# How to fix fatal error Fatal error: Class CI_Session_files_driver (Code Igniter)?

Tags: codeigniter, session

I have to projects on my local server. The were working perfectly. I didn't change anything at all. But when I went to look at them today I got the following **error**:

> Fatal error: Class **CI_Session_files_driver** contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (SessionHandlerInterface::open) in C:\xampp\htdocs\ci\system\libraries\Session\drivers\Session_files_driver.php on line 49

I found another post at [Fatal error: Class CI_Session_files_driver contains 1 abstract method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34896271/fatal-error-class-ci-session-files-driver-contains-1-abstract-method) that had the same issue.

However, the answer said this problem was caused becasue changes were made in the system folder. However, I never changed the system folder. Other comments suggested making changes to the system file in question. I tried these changes, despite other comments advising to not change the file, but the changes did not help.

I'm beyond baffled, because I never made a change to any of my files. The applications were working fine yesterday. Suddenly, they are broken.

Comment: show some codes of the problem

Comment: My two (not "to") applications are now working again on my local server, xampp. I know it sounds unbelievable, but I didn't make any changes to the code. I was just reviewing the UX and suddently the apps broke and I got the error described above. Suddenly again, they've resumed working. I'm happy again , but still baffled as to why.

Comment: did you change the php version??

Answer (score -6):

Problem solved restarting apache.

I attach the url who saves me: http://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-64763.html

Comment: Don't be oversmart. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36209574/codeigniter-database-session-error